# display text in tableviewcolumn in treeView QtQuick controls 1.4

Tags: qml, qtquickcontrols, qt5.5

Im trying to create a simple treeView appeared in Qt 5.5 , the problem is that the text in items of the tree doesn't display, despite the model is full.

There is my code :

TreeViewPM.qml

Qt Code:
Switch view

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQml.Models 2.2
import KMTreeModelPM 1.0

Item {

    KMTreeModelPM {
        id: treeModel
    }

    ItemSelectionModel {
        id: sel
        model: treeModel
    }
    Text {
        id:txt
        text: " "
    }


    TreeView {
        id: view
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins:  12
        selection: sel
        headerVisible : false
        itemDelegate: Rectangle {
                   color: ( styleData.row % 2 == 0 ) ? "white" : "lightblue"
                   height: 20

                   Text {
                       anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                       anchors.left: parent.left // by default x is set to 0 so this had no effect
                       text: styleData.value
                   }
               }
        TableViewColumn {
            id : title
            title: "Title"
            role: "title"
            resizable: true
            horizontalAlignment : Text.AlignLeft
        }
        model: treeModel

        onDoubleClicked: txt.text = treeModel.data(index,0) 

    }

}
```

To copy to clipboard, switch view to plain text mode

main.qml

Qt Code:
Switch view

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQml.Models 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4

Rectangle {
    width: 785
        TabView {
            x: 17
            y: 8
            width: 970
            height: 800
            currentIndex: 2
            visible: true
            Tab {
                id: tabAddProfile
                title: qsTr("Add Profile")
                AddProfilePage{}
            }
            Tab {
                id: tabAddTypeSubType
                title: qsTr("Add Type/SubType")
                AddTypeSubTypePage{}
            }
            Tab {
                id: tabAddDetail
                height: 413
                visible: true
                title: qsTr("Add Detail")
                TreeViewPM {}
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably your model. It's hard to know when we don't have access to it.

The following works:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QtQml>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QtGui>

static void initStandardTreeModel(QStandardItemModel *model)
{
    QStandardItem *item;
    item = new QStandardItem(QLatin1String("Row 1 Item"));
    model->insertRow(0, item);

    item = new QStandardItem(QLatin1String("Row 2 Item"));
    item->setCheckable(true);
    model->insertRow(1, item);

    QStandardItem *childItem = new QStandardItem(QLatin1String("Row 2 Child Item"));
    item->setChild(0, childItem);

    item = new QStandardItem(QLatin1String("Row 3 Item"));
    item->setIcon(QIcon());
    model->insertRow(2, item);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QStandardItemModel* model = new QStandardItemModel();
    initStandardTreeModel(model);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("theModel", model);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    width: 800
    height: 400
    visible: true

    TreeView {
        id: view
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins:  12

        TableViewColumn {
            id : title
            title: "Title"
            role: "display"
        }
        model: theModel
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried your code (in PyQt), but still text not showing.